# Python - Ask the user for two numbers and draw a number triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Im supposed to ask the user for two numbers (x,y). The first number defines what number the triangle will start with and the second number defines how many levels the triangle will have.

For example,

(1,2)

```
1
2 3
```

(3,4)

```
3
4 5
6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

This is what I have for now:

```
x = int(input("Eliga el primer parámetro: "))
y = int(input("Eliga el segundo parámetro: "))  
x = x
y = y
for i in range(1,y+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(x, end=" ")
    print()
```

but I get a triangle with x's:
Example (2, 4):

```
2 
2 2 
2 2 2 
2 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment x, and you don't need to assign x and y to themselves.

```
x = int(input("Eliga el primer parámetro: "))
y = int(input("Eliga el segundo parámetro: "))  
for i in range(1,y+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        # now increment x:
        x =+ 1
        print(x-1, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: I tried your code but it gives me this:

2
11
111
1111

Comment: @IreneCastañeda - sorry, the end=" "  was throwing me off. Try this.

Comment: For some reason it now gives me a triangle made up of zeros.

Comment: Can you take out that end="" call?

Comment: I think that's what makes it a triangle instead of lines.

Comment: If this is python 3, could you please add that tag to your original post? The versions are drastically different in respects like this.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

```
def emit(x,y):
    i,n,C = x-1,0,1
    while C<y+1:
        i += 1
        n += 1
        if n<C:
            yield("%02d " % i)
        else:
            yield('%02d\n' % i)
            n = 0
            C += 1

print(''.join(emit(5,6)))
```